# InfoPath 2010 Data Connection Server Side Filtering

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a repeating table and I filter this repeating table at client side. But now I have a large amount of data and filtering this needs much time and in IE8 there is warning about long running script. I want to filter this data at server side or in data connection. How can I do this? What must I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you retrieve the data from SharePoint but, in my opinion, the best solution would be to create a custom WebService which only returns the filtered data (using CAML query). Then you can add this web service as WebService DataSource to your InfoPath and simple query it like a SharePoint List DataSource.

Comment: Can I use SharePoint2010 web services for this? Such as /_vti_bin/dspsts.asmx?

Comment: Also, can I solve this without a custom web service? I want to solve this only using SPDesigner2010 and DataConnection. Can I use CAML for this?